# async/await throws error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'xyz' of undefined", but not always

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a simple code that prompts for user input and then does something with the input. In the *trial run* of the code, I get **error:** `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined`, but not always. I don't understand why it throws the error only sometimes?

---

**input-interface.js**

```
'use strict';

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

module.exports = {
  prompt: function prompt(question) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      rl.setPrompt(question);
      rl.prompt();
      rl.once("line", resolve);
    });
  }
}
```

**interactive-request-procedures.js**

```
'use strict'

const input_interface = require('./input_interface');
const InteractiveRequestProcedures = Object.create(input_interface);

InteractiveRequestProcedures.createInputNode = async function createInputNode() {
  return {
    position: await this.prompt("Position? start(s), end(e), position(integer) > "),
    value: await this.prompt("Value? > "),
  };  
}

InteractiveRequestProcedures.inputRemoveKey = async function inputRemoveKey() {
  return await this.prompt("Remove Key? > ");
}

InteractiveRequestProcedures.requestProcedure = async function requestProcedure() {
  const procedure = await this.prompt("Procedure? insert(i), delete(d) > ");

  if (procedure === "i") {
    return {
      procedure,
      node: await this.createInputNode(),
    }   
  } else if (procedure === "d") {
    return {
      procedure,
      node: await this.inputRemoveKey(),
    }   
  } else {
    console.log(`Invalid input '${procedure}': Please select again\n`);
    await this.requestProcedure();
  }
}

module.exports = InteractiveRequestProcedures;
```

**main-program.js**

The line at which `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined` occurs is highlighted with a comment in the code below.

```
'use strict';

const LinkedList = Object.create(require('./interactive-request-procedures'));

LinkedList.setup = function setup() {
  this.lhead = -1;

  this.last = -1;


  this.free = -1;

  this.key = [];
  this.next = [];
  this.prev = [];

  this.listLength = 0;

  this.input();
}

LinkedList.input = async function input() {
  while(true) {
    let input = await this.requestProcedure(); //UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
    let { position, value } = input.node;

    if (input.procedure === "i") {
      switch (position) {
        case '1':
        case 's':
          this.prepend(value); // implementation details not shown
          break;
        case 'e':
        case `${this.next.length}`:
          this.append(value); // implementation details not shown
          break;
        default:
          /* Check to see if position is an integer */
          if ( (position ^ 0) === parseInt(position, 10) ) {
            console.log(`Invalid input: Position ${position} is not an integer`);
            continue;
          }

          /* Check to see if position exceeds list length */
          if (position > this.listLength) {
            console.log(`Invalid input: Position ${position} exceeds list length ${this.listLength}\nTry Again\n`);
            continue;
          }

          this.insertAt(value, position); // implementation details not shown
      }
    }

    if (input.procedure === 'd') this.deleteNode(input.node);

    const resp = await this.prompt("Continue? y / n > ");
    if (resp === "n")
      break;
    console.log("\n");
  }
  console.log(this.list);
}

LinkedList.setup();
```

---

**Trial run**

I execute the code with `node main-program.js`

```
me@myBook ~/main-program (master) $ node skip-list.js 
Procedure? insert(i), delete(d) > aef
Invalid input 'aef': Please select again

Procedure? insert(i), delete(d) > i
Position? start(s), end(e), position(integer) > 2332
Value? > 23
(node:41451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
    at Object.input (main-program.js:51:34)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:41451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (reject
ion id: 1)
(node:41451) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

me@myBook ~/main-program (master) $ node skip-list.js 
Procedure? insert(i), delete(d) > i
Position? start(s), end(e), position(integer) > 3232
Value? > 2
Invalid input: Position 3232 is not an integer
Procedure? insert(i), delete(d) > i
Position? start(s), end(e), position(integer) > 234
Value? > 34
Invalid input: Position 234 is not an integer
Procedure? insert(i), delete(d) > 244355
Invalid input '244355': Please select again

Procedure? insert(i), delete(d) > i
Position? start(s), end(e), position(integer) > 3232
Value? > 224
(node:41455) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
    at Object.input (main-program.js:51:34)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:41455) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (reject
ion id: 1)
(node:41455) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Value? > 434
```

Comment: When we use async and await we need to use try catch block to handle the errors

Comment: usually this type of errors happens when an exception or error occurred, i believe that you can solve this problem by putting try catch after debugging your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should always use a try...catch block around async/await code, this will not help solve the problem of "why does it sometimes work and sometimes fail?"

Your problem is in this block of code:

```
} else {
    console.log(`Invalid input '${procedure}': Please select again\n`);
    await this.requestProcedure();
}
```

After entering an invalid input, this block of code will not supply a return value from the function.

To reproduce your issue:

- start the program
- enter invalid input
- application displays: Invalid input '${procedure}': Please select again
- enter valid input
- Exception thrown (Cannot read property 'node')

To resolve the issue, simply return in the last else:

```
} else {
    console.log(`Invalid input '${procedure}': Please select again\n`);
    return await this.requestProcedure();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to handle the errors, to prevent from this kind of exceptions

When we use async await, we need to use 'try catch' block
When we use promises, we need to use 'then and catch' block

```
try {
 // positive case
} catch(error) {
 // handle errors here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronous operation in this line:

`let input = await this.requestProcedure();`

Is failing so the `input` variable isn't being set. Because of this, when it goes on to execute the next line:

`let { position, value } = input.node;`

You get `Cannot read property 'node' of undefined` because input doesn't contain a value. 
You should execute async commands inside a try catch so that you can see the details of the error:

```
try {
    let input = await this.requestProcedure();
    // run the rest of your code
}
catch(error) {
    // Do something with the error (e.g. log it, print it)
}
```

Unfortunately we can't say for sure what is causing the problem with the async operation but this is the reason for the error you have mentioned in your question. This will also help you to debug it.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I will take care to follow proper structure for `async/await`. Still my main concern is the reason for the error.